# Query With Sub Category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server; is it possible to get the desired output using a query?

I have a view (`Table_A`) which contains issue details for a production order:

```
Prod No Item No Quantity Value
-------------------------------
  4      A001     10      250
  4      A002     15      175
  4      A003     17      250
```

Another view (`Table_B`) which contains the receipt details for a production order:

```
Prod No  Item No  Quantity  Total Value
----------------------------------------
  4       FG001      1          675
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
Prod No   Item No  Quantity   Total Value
-----------------------------------------
  4        FG001      1          675
  4        A001       10         250
  4        A002       15         175
  4        A003       17         250
```

Comment: ***WHY*** are you **views** called `Table_A` and `Table_B` ?? This is highly confusing - and violates the very fundamental *Principle Of Least Surprise*. If it's a **view** - call it like that (e.g. `VIew_A`) - if you call something a `Table.....`, everyone will (rightfully) assume it's really a **TABLE** (not a view) :....

Answer (score 2):

do union all

```
select prodno,item,quentity,Value as totalvalue  from Table_A
union all
select prodno,item,quentity,totalvalue  from Table_B
```